# Why is my table caption in italic by default? How can I change it?

Tags: tables, fonts

My table caption is italic by default while my figure captions are not. Is there any way I can make my table captions the same as the figures' ones?

[image][image]

These are the code for my table, which is absolutely normal. I don't think I have any preference specified at the beginning of the document that would cause this problem.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\small
  \centering % centering table
  
    \begin{tabular}{rl l l l l }
 ***
    \end{tabular}
   \caption{test}
  \label{tab:mnist}%
\end{table}%
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm unable to reproduce the issue you're reporting if I make your code snippet *minimally compilable* by prefixing `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` and affixing `\end{document}`. Hence, the code you've posted so far is not what's causing the issue. Please do tell us which document class you employ, whether or not the document class or your preamble loads the `caption` package and, if so, with which options the package is loaded. Do either the document class or the preamble contain a line such as `\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=sc, textfont=it, labelsep=newline}`?

Comment: Alright, turns out I am using the wrong documentclass. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Are you saying that the formatting issue has resolved itself?

Comment: Yes, thank you.